# Can an external Javascript file be called and executed depending on a conditional?

Tags: javascript

I know that I can run an external Javascript file from within HTML with the following syntax:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://somesite.com/location/of/javascript.js">
</script>
```

This will result in `http://somesite.com/location/of/javascript.js` being run the moment the browser reads that line of the HTML.

But is there a way I can run an external Javascript file from within Javascript? Something like:

```
if (x == 1)
{
 run this! -> http://somesite.com/location/of/javascript.js;
}
```

Obviously that's not valid code. But I can't find any example of what might be the right way to do this (if it exists), because all the help text I find with Google searches tell me how to run Javascript from within HTML

I know that I can include a Javascript file and then call functions within it. However, in this situation, I do not have any control over `http://somesite.com/location/of/javascript.js`, and it is designed to execute the moment it is called. I can't change how it works, so I need to figure out how to call it at the right time in the right way.

Is there a way I can get it to be called and executed immediately depending on a conditional statement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, in Pure Javascript you can Load javascript dynamically

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "test.js";
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a way...

```
var extfile = document.createElement('script')
extfile.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
extfile.setAttribute("src", external_jsfilename)
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(extfile)
```

Simple as that ....

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's [.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) the file will be loaded and then executed

```
if (x == 1)
    {
     $.getScript( "http://somesite.com/location/of/javascript.js");
    }
```